# How to pass an Authorization token for AFNetworking 2.0 as it is deprecated

Tags: ios8, http-headers, token, afnetworking-2, afhttprequestoperation

I'm Currently working on a project where I'm using AFNetworking 2.0 library to GET and POST the data to and from server.In some cases i wanted to pass a token value as header type for the request with AFHTTPRequestOperationManager. So far this is what i found

```
[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithToken:TOKEN_VALUE];
```

but it is deprecated in version 2.0, and i also learned in version AFNetWorking 2.2.1 it is not deprecated. But i couldn't find the library with version 2.2.1 to download it.
Please help me out if there is any other way that i can set token as my header for AFHTTPRequestOperationManager. And also any link to download the AFNetworking latest version library.

Answer (score 3):

This is the deprecation message in the AFNetworking docs:

> This method has been deprecated. Use setValue:forHTTPHeaderField: instead. (Deprecated: This method has been deprecated. Use -setValue:forHTTPHeaderField: instead.)

The docs for this method `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:` can be found [here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.4.1/Classes/AFHTTPRequestSerializer.html#//api/name/setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:). To set a token as your header with the AFNetworking method `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:` try:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] initWithBaseURL:@"http://someurl.com"];

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Token token=token_name" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Comment: whenever i use [setValue: forHTTPHeaderField: ] method i can't send any value for @"Authorization" field. But could successfully send value for the @"Content-Type" field. Can anyone help me out of this?